# WP Fieldmanager nested groups only sortable when Add More button is present

Tags: wordpress, fieldmanager

Trying to create an set number of groups nested in a larger group. Want to have the ability to sort the nested groups. This only works when Add More is present. Does anyone know how to make these groups sortable?

[image]

Comment: I suggest posting your code. Did you set `'sortable' => true,`?

Comment: Yes I used `'sortable' => true`, but that only seemed to work when I added `limit = 0`

Comment: `public function builder() {
    return new \Fieldmanager_Group( [
      'name'           => 'builder',
      'children'       => [
        'sortable_area' => new \Fieldmanager_Group( [
          'tabbed'         => false,
          'label'          => 'Sortable Area',
          'children'       => [
            'part_one_group' => new \Fieldmanager_Group( [
              'label'          => 'Part 1 Group',
              'sortable' => true,
              'children'       => [
              //
              ],
            ] ),
            ] ),`

Comment: Haven't used it in a while, but if I recall, I don't think the parents are sortable if the children are too. If you move the `'sortable' => true` before your children array does that mess it up?

Comment: So I want the children of sortable area to be sortable, not the parent. When I move it to the parent only the parent is sortable.

Comment: Oh okay. Well I just tried putting in a non-zero limit on some old code for a group and it was still sortable. Granted, my code looks way different. Sorry I can't be of more help.